# Windows Service Memory Usage Increases

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-leaks, timer, windows-services

I have a windows service doing 3 scheduled jobs. First of them is sending an email to employees their shift times. Second one is getting Active Directory information and saving it to local database. Last one is saving active directory photos to file directory.

Each job is done on a separate thread. Timer ticks every 45 seconds. Everything is running perfectly except the memory usage by the service which is increasing steadily.

Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

```
Thread[] thread;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Interval = 1000 * 45;
    timer.Start();
    timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    servisList = new List<IService>() { new ShiftNotification(), new     ActiveDirectoryService(), new DirectoryPhotos() };
    thread = new Thread[servisList.Count];
}

private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < servisList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (thread[i] == null)
            {
                if (TimeControl.CheckTime(DateTime.Now, servisList.ElementAt(i).sProps))
                {
                    thread[i] = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(servisList.ElementAt(i).NotifyUsers));
                    thread[i].Start();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (thread[i].ThreadState != System.Threading.ThreadState.Running)
                {
                    if (TimeControl.CheckTime(DateTime.Now, servisList.ElementAt(i).sProps))
                    {
                        thread[i] = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(servisList.ElementAt(i).NotifyUsers));
                        thread[i].Start();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a few ideas for this

1. Both `ActiveDirectory` and `SmcpClient` (correct me if you aren't using it for emails) usage means that you're dealing with unmanaged resources, are you disposing those classes correctly? You probably should make client variables as static fields and dispose them at the end of your program.
2. These lines are unclear for me:

   ```
   if (thread[i].ThreadState != System.Threading.ThreadState.Running)
   {
       if (TimeControl.CheckTime(DateTime.Now, servisList.ElementAt(i).sProps))
       {
           thread[i] = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(servisList.ElementAt(i).NotifyUsers));
           thread[i].Start();
       }
   }
   ```

   `Thread` is unmanaged resource too, so, as it's implementing the `IDisposable`, you should dispose previous one before assigning the new value for the array entry: `thread[i].Dispose();`
3. *minor* Why do you use full names as you already added `using System.Threading`?

Comment: 1) You are right. I am using ActiveDirectory and SmtpClient classes. I wasn't aware that I had to dispose these objects. 2) I have certain tasks that run on a separate thread. I control it via a TimeControl class. Also if the thread is in Running state I don't want to assign a new value and start it. 3) My bad! I deleted it from my code.

Comment: In 2 bullet, are you saying that I need to implement IDisposable?

Comment: You can override the `Dispose` handler for one of your form or dispose those objects during closing the application. Just implementing the `IDisposable` is not enough - you have to clear your resources. It's up to you how exactly to do it.

Comment: @SeckinCelik, give a try to the TPL with long-running tasks, if version of the .Net framework greater than 3.6 is an option

Comment: It is a windows service therefore it runs until I stop it. I guess handling disposing prior to closing won't work out for me. I will give a try to TPL.

Comment: If you create local variables, you need to dispose them, forexample, with `using` statement

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, it isn't possible to answer this without more specific information about what you are doing in that NotifyUsers method.

But even before looking into that, I would first revisit this thread-spawning logic you've got there, with this

```
if (thread[i] == null)
{
   // (code omitted)
}
else
{
   // (code omitted)
}
```

By that, I mean, first try to figure out whether or not your service ends up spawning too many of those worker threads, to begin with (which is my wild guess, a priori).

More specifically, as soon as / every time you're using System.Threading.Thread, always think of [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) as one of the first / most likely issues to be aware of.

Multi-threading is never easy. But [plenty of resources](http://www.albahari.com/threading) are out there to help you get it done right.

'Hope this helps.

Comment: There are only 3 threads created and re-run if the the thread state is not "Running". Each thread takes about 5 to 10 minutes to complete. NotifyUsers method is getting Active Directoyr users which is about 800 and save/update on local database.

Comment: @SeckinCelik : if you are confident that there aren't too many threads created, then I would investigate (by memory profiling) as to why whatever data they're gathering from AD (likely) doesn't get garbage-collected as it should and (likely) keeps piling up onto your service process' memory. A good practice is to develop Windows services as standalone console applications first, to ease the debugging and profiling.

Comment: More specifically, things to watch out for: static and runtime scopes of your variables and class type fields (e.g., any statics? and/or object reference cycles making too many instances still reachable from the GC roots? etc)

Comment: One resource you may find useful : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/10.0/Analyzing_GC_Roots.html